# How hibernate store embeddable obj

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, embeddable

kind of stupid question but i didn't find the answer anywhere. How @Embeddable object is stored in the database, is it kind of OneToOne with FK or... For example if i have:

```
@Entity
public class User {
   private Long id;

   @Id 
   public Long getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }


   private Address address;

   @Embedded 
   public Address getAddress() { return address; }
   public void setAddress() { this.address = address; }
}


@Embeddable
public class Address {
   private String street1;

   public String getStreet1() { return street1; }
   public void setStreet1() { this.street1 = street1; }
}
```

How the table(s) should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embedded object's fields are added as columns to the table of the owning Entity.

So you will have a table `User` with fields `id` and `street1`.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: all columns from the embedded object will be merged into columns of the parent, resulting with a single table. In your example you will end up with a table `User` containing columns: `id` and `street1`. So embedded objects are basically a way to logically group columns within one table.